# How to repair wall next to external door?

Tags: repair, walls, hole, hole-repair

I [did some repairs a while back](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/88822/new-door-jamb-is-smaller-than-the-one-it-replaced-can-i-use-it), replacing a damaged door jamb.

That repair left some damage to the neighboring wall, as shown in the photos below.
I am getting a new pre-hung door soon, and want to repair the wall before the door is installed. Is this as straightforward as *spackle->sand->paint*, or is there more involved that I don't know? The wall is plaster by the way.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Depends on who is hanging the door. If it's you then the answer below from Jamie is correct. If it's someone else you would want the wall repaired so when they hang the door they could install the trim and be done. Otherwise they'd have to wait for you to repair the wall and come back a second time to do the trim.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose big box store is installing the door. That is to say, they are contracting it out.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see in those images, I wouldn't bother repairing that drywall until the new door is in. Sometimes hanging/fitting a door requires a lot of work to get it plumb, straight, and level, and that may cause you to damage what you just repaired.

Once the new door is installed, you can see how the wall will need to be repaired relative to the new jambs. 95% of the time you'd just cover something like that with the trim and be done with it- no mudding or sanding needed, and only repairing if you have a gap or crack beyond what the trim covers.